# Google Site creation using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, google-sites

I am working on a C# application to create a [Google Site](https://sites.google.com/), but I am unable to find any sample code for it. Any help in C# or VB.Net will be greatly appreciated.

Please help!!!

Thanks to all...

Comment: What do you mean by 'create Google Site'?

Comment: sites.google.com - part of Google apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation for the Google Sitesd API as a whole can be found here: http://code.google.com/apis/sites/.

This is the only "official" sample I could find using C# but it's not for creating a site: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/sites/dotnet/SitesAPIDemo.cs.

The raw XML protocol for creating a site can be found here: http://code.google.com/apis/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#SitesFeedPOST. But note that...

> This feature is only available to Google Apps domains.

Comment: any idea of how to use the raw XML protocol?  any code help would be greatly appreciated..Thanks

Comment: I believe the C# sample I linked to demonstrates how to use an XML protocol (via Google's GData library). Although it's not doing a "create site", the principles of how to communicate with the API should be the same.

Comment: so, does it mean that I can create a XML to create the site and pass it to FeedQuery object?

Comment: I have no experience with either GData or the Google Sites API so my answer is "possibly".

Comment: I am working also working on Google Site API.My Code is---------------------------------------        SiteEntry entry = new SiteEntry();
            entry.Title = new AtomTextConstruct(AtomTextConstructElementType.Title, Title);
            entry.Summary = new AtomTextConstruct(AtomTextConstructElementType.Summary, Summary);  
            try
            {
                AtomEntry inserted = service.Insert(new Uri(makeFeedUri("site")), entry);
            }
            catch (GDataRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ResponseString);
            }

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing a .NET application to help people create their own Google sites? Are you looking for a .NET sample for http://code.google.com/apis/sites/?

Does this help? http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/dotnet_client_lib.html

Also, see http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/sites/dotnet/SitesAPIDemo.cs

Comment: Michael, The second one is correct, I am trying to write a .Net app. to help people create their own Google Sites...Any ideas?